# What's the complexity of variable assignment of a string in Python? Constant or length of string

Tags: python, time-complexity

In Python:

```
hello = "hello"

# What's the complexity of this operation?
wow = hello
```

Is it `O(length of hello)`, or constant? And what if `wow` was instantiated before already?

What I wonder is whether Python copies the string `O(n)`, or just creates a reference that points to the string (since strings are immutable)?

Many thanks

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a good explanation of Python variables and assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is constant because just create a reference.

You can test with:

```
a = "Hello"
b = a

print(id(a),id(b))
```

It's return same address.